# Python question about reading two txt and output one txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
week5_worldarea.txt:                     week5_worldpop.txt:

China 9388211                            China 1415045928
India 2973190                            India 1354051854
U.S. 9147420                             U.S. 326766748
Indonesia 1811570                        Indonesia 266794980
Brazil 8358140                           Brazil 210867954
Pakistan 770880                          Pakistan 200813818
Nigeria 910770                           Nigeria 195875237
Bangladesh 130170                        Bangladesh 166368149
Russia 16376870                          Russia 143964709
Mexico 1943950                           Mexico 130759074
Japan 364555                             Japan 127185332
Ethiopia 1000000                         Ethiopia 107534882
Philippines 298170                       Philippines 106512074
Egypt 995450                             Egypt 99375741
Viet-Nam 310070                          Viet-Nam 96491146
DR-Congo 2267050                         DR-Congo 84004989
Germany 348560                           Germany 82293457
Iran 1628550                             Iran 82011735
Turkey 769630                            Turkey 81916871
Thailand 510890                          Thailand 69183173
U.K. 241930                              U.K. 66573504
France 547557                            France 65233271
Italy 294140                             Italy 59290969
```

Hello, I have two text files as you can see. I want to create a third txt which contains Country Name 
    and population density. For example:

```
China 150.7258
India 455.420
.....
```

To do this, I code a python file called untitled2 which contains these functions :

```
def get_area(x):
    pos1=x.find(' ')
    area=x[pos1+1:len(x)]
    return area

def get_country(x):
    pos2=x.find(' ')
    country=x[0:pos2]
    return country

def get_pop(x):
    pos3=x.find(' ')
    pop=x[pos3+1:len(x)]
    return pop
```

and another python file called untitled3 is :

```
import untitled2

f1=open('week5_worldarea.txt','r')    
f2=open('week5_worldpop.txt','r')
f3=open('week5_worlddensity1.txt','w')



for line1 in f1:

    float(untitled2.get_area(line1))

for line2 in f2:
    float(untitled2.get_pop(line2))
density=float(untitled2.get_pop(line2))/float(untitled2.get_area(line1))


for line3 in f1:
    untitled2.get_country(line3)

f3.write(str(line3)+str(density))


f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()
```

I think there is a problem with loops but I don't know how to correct it. Also I use some expressions like pos1=x.find(' ') but is there any way to express it by using tabs? I mean, if I write pos1=x.find('\t'), will it be wrong? Thanks so much.

Comment: You aren't saving any of the data you read from either into file. Further, the third loop won't do anything, because you have already read the entire contents of `f1`.

Comment: When you compute `density`, `line1` and `line2` are just the last lines of each file.

Comment: I know this is a duplicate, but can't locate any of the previous references.  Anyone else?

Comment: I revised my code and I now get Italy 294140 201.57397497790168. There should be a small change to make it correct, but I still cannot find.

Comment: The only reason you get Italy is because after you have read through each file, `line1` and `line2` still contain the last line of input from each file. You aren't saving any of the data you compute in the body of the loops. `line3` never gets set at all, because you have already read everything from `f1`.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I still can't get how I can fix it, sorry. Should I use nested for loops? I tried some nested loops but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You want to read each of the two files in lockstep, and you can write the density for each country as you compute it. (I'm assuming the two input files have the same countries on corresponding lines.)

```
with open('week5_worldarea.txt') as area_f, \
     open('week5_worldpop.txt') as pop_f, \
     open('week5_worlddensity1.txt', 'w') as dens_f:

    for area_l, pop_l in zip(area_f, pop_f):
        country1, area = area_l.split()
        country2, pop = pop_l.split()
        assert country1 == country2
        density = int(pop)/int(area)
        dens_f.write(str(density))
```

Comment: The provider of the question solved it like you but I want a solution by using functions. Thanks.

Comment: There are nearly an infinite number of ways to "use functions". What exactly are you looking for? You have to either use the data in one iteration before reading the next line, or you need to save it in memory for later.

Comment: By using untitled2, I think that I have country names and numbers, the only thing I need to do is to make proper calculations and placements in untitled3, thats it. I just cannot find a way to do it.

Comment: I revised my code and I now get Italy 294140 201.57397497790168. There should be a small change to make it correct, but I still cannot find.